# Iterate each dropdown and read and save html table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to iterate dropdown and then trying to read html table and want to save it in excel but I am getting an error:Tables not found

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.transferofvalue.ie/')
a=['ABBVIE LTD','BAYER LTD','ASTRAZENECA']
table = driver.page_source

for i in a:
    select_box =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='BodyContent__company']")
    select_box.send_keys(i)
    #time.sleep(10)
    ds=pd.read_html(table,index_col=None)[2]
    c=pd.DataFrame(ds)
    c.to_excel('ranking_{}.xlsx'.format(i),index=False)
```

Comment: this code work fine when i manually enter company name but don't work under condition of for loop...Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `driver.page_source` with every loop:

```
for i in a:
    select_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='BodyContent__company']")
    select_box.send_keys(i)
    time.sleep(5)
    table = driver.page_source
    time.sleep(2)
    ds = pd.read_html(table)[2]
    c=pd.DataFrame(ds)
    c.to_excel('ranking_{}.xlsx'.format(i))
```

Comment: Thank u so much it works perfectly but i was getting error with index but after removing index=False it works fine..Once again thank u

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I removed the "index = False" from the upper solution. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, which is helpful to other people.